# "Whom" or "to whom"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

Could someone please inform me which of the following would be more correct :

> " This was the last man whom I told there was no hope. "

or :

> " This was the last man to whom I told there was no hope. "

?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The former would be the correct form ("This was the last man whom I told there was no hope").

"To whom" is usually used when it is a question: "To whom was the letter addressed?"

Comment: It has to do with the verb, not whether it's a question. "The letter was addressed to him" would be correct. "To whom did you tell there was no hope" would not.

Answer (score 2):

If we rearrange "This was the last man to whom I told there was no hope.", we get "I told to this man there was no hope." This is incorrect, because we do not use "to" in this situation. If the verb were "say", that would be correct:  "This was the last man to whom I said that there was no hope."